# Почему при смене слайдов отсчет всегда начинается с 0px?

Tags: javascript, jquery

При нажатии на кнопку смены слайда каждый раз происходит отсчет с 0px и слайд начинает прокручиваться с 1 слайда. Как сделать перелистывание слайда с той точки на которой я уже нахожусь.  Как я понимаю использовать translate3d можно только в качестве step? и метод `.animate` дублирует `transition` из css? [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRQwAj)

```
     (document).ready(function() {
  $(".project-gallerey").each(function () { // обрабатываем каждый слайдер
    var obj = $(this);
    $(obj).append("<div class='pagination-gallerey'></div>");
    $(obj).find(".slider-image").each(function () {
      $(obj).find(".pagination-gallerey").append("<span class='nav-pengetation' rel='"+$(this).index()+"'></span>"); // добавляем блок навигации
      $(this).addClass("slider"+$(this).index());
    });
    $(obj).find("span").first().addClass("on"); // делаем активным первый элемент меню
  });
});
function sliderJS (obj, sl) { // slider function
  var ul = $(sl).find("ul"); // находим блок
  var bl = $(sl).find("li.slider"+obj); // находим любой из элементов блока
  var step = $(bl).width(); // ширина объекта
  $(ul).animate({'opacity': step*obj
                }, {
    step: function (now, fx) {
      $(this).css({"transform": "translate3d( " + - now  + "px, 0px,  0px)"});
    },
    duration: 500,
    easing: 'linear',
    queue: false,
    complete: function () {
    }
  }, 'linear'); // 500 это скорость перемотки
}
$(document).on("click", ".nav-pengetation", function() { // slider click navigate
  var sl = $(this).closest(".project-gallerey"); // находим, в каком блоке был клик
  $(sl).find("span").removeClass("on"); // убираем активный элемент
  $(this).addClass("on"); // делаем активным текущий
  var obj = $(this).attr("rel"); // узнаем его номер
  sliderJS(obj, sl); // слайдим
  return false;
});
```

Comment: весь необходимый код должен быть **непосредственно** в вопросе, ссылки могут служить лишь дополнением

Comment: где вызывается _sliderJS_?

Comment: свойство `opacity` отвечает за прозрачность, и обычно его значения от 0 до 1

Comment: @Grundy это ясно за что отвечает opacity. Но почему значения уходят в 0? собственно пример кода с translate3d брал здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27302395/animate-translate3d-with-jquery

Comment: потому что на самом деле значение не с 0, а с 1 идут

Comment: @Grundy я имею ввиду когда выбираешь 1 слайд. Значения уходят в 0. Почему вычисление происходит в NaN ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключается в непонимании того, как работает [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

В передаваемом объекте указываются конечные значения свойств, jQuery берет **текущее** значение и рассчитывает шаги.

В случае со свойством `opacity` - браузеры, по крайней мере хром, хранят его значения в диапазоне от 0 до 1, таким образом при клике на вторую, третью кнопки, движение начиналось не с ожидаемого значения(например 320), а с текущего - 1.

Первый слайд убирался, потому что у него индекс - 0, а для него выставлялось новое значение свойства `opacity` в 0 - что значит абсолютно прозрачный элемент.

Кроме того, в данном случае лучше использовать какое-то несуществующее свойство, чтобы не влиять на остальные настройки.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".project-gallerey").each(function() { // обрабатываем каждый слайдер
    var obj = $(this);
    $(obj).append("<div class='pagination-gallerey'></div>");
    $(obj).find(".slider-image").each(function() {
      $(obj).find(".pagination-gallerey").append("<span class='nav-pengetation' rel='" + $(this).index() + "'></span>"); // добавляем блок навигации
      $(this).addClass("slider" + $(this).index());
    });
    $(obj).find("span").first().addClass("on"); // делаем активным первый элемент меню
  });
});

function sliderJS(obj, sl) { // slider function
  var ul = $(sl).find("ul"); // находим блок
  var bl = $(sl).find("li.slider" + obj); // находим любой из элементов блока
  var step = $(bl).width(); // ширина объекта
  $(ul).animate({
    'propForTransformAnimation': step * (+obj)
  }, {
    step: function(now, fx) {
      $(this).css({
        "transform": "translate3d( " + -now + "px, 0px,  0px)"
      });
    },
    duration: 500,
    easing: 'linear',
    queue: false,
    complete: function() {}
  }, 'linear'); // 500 это скорость перемотки
}
$(document).on("click", ".nav-pengetation", function() { // slider click navigate
  var sl = $(this).closest(".project-gallerey"); // находим, в каком блоке был клик
  $(sl).find("span").removeClass("on"); // убираем активный элемент
  $(this).addClass("on"); // делаем активным текущий
  var obj = $(this).attr("rel"); // узнаем его номер
  sliderJS(obj, sl); // слайдим
  return false;
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.project-gallerey {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
.project-info {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.nav-pengetation {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-pengetation:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.slider-gallerey {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sliders-wrapper {
  width: 2500px;
  padding: 0;
}
.slider-image {
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
}
.base {
  width: 220px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="base">
  <div class="close-modal"></div>
  <div class="project-gallerey">

    <div class="slider-gallerey">
      <ul class="sliders-wrapper">
        <li class="slider-image">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1" alt="">
        </li>
        <li class="slider-image">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100/e499e4/fff&amp;text=2" alt="">
        </li>
        <li class="slider-image">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100/e499e4/fff&amp;text=3" alt="">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А зачем экранировать в скобки (+obj)?

Comment: @Drop, на автомате сделал, в любом случае, такие неочевидные преобразования лучше выделять, чтобы сразу было видно